# How to connect from one VM Guest instance to another to another VM Guest instance

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have `Windows 7 as my Host OS` and I have a VM guest instance of `CentOs 6`, now I have created a more Instance guest `Centos 6` via `Vagrant`. All are working fine and I am able to do a ssh/ping from Windows(Host) to both guest OS, but I am not able to do a `ssh` or `ping` from one guest to another.

Is is possible to  interconnect two VM Guest Instance ?

Comment: What type of Networking (e.g., NAT, bridged, internal, host-only) did you choose in Virtualbox for each network interface in each VM?

Comment: have you created both VM via vagrant or different way?

Comment: I have created one by manualy ie imported vm setup of centos with lamp stack and another with vagrant

Comment: @mark I didn't choose both vm instance it was set already , both are running with different ips

Comment: then your network in different range . vagrant default network is different than default network of manual created VM .

Comment: Oh that means wont be possible to connect ? But I connect to both guest os via ssh via putty

Comment: What I meant from windows I can connect to both

Comment: yes , you will be able from window . bcoz that is virtual switch/ router in between Internet and guest .

Comment: wait i am giving answer .you will understand easy .

Comment: You'll probably need to change the network type in your virtualization program/solution. From NATed to bridged seems to me the best option, bridged will be as if it is a host in your network, it'll get the IPs from the same DHCP server, your computer (probably) gets his IPs.

Answer (score 2):

you have created  VM one by manually and second one by vagrant . so , both using different default network generally for manual it create `192.168.122.0/24` ( in libvirt) and vagrant default network `192.168.121.0/24` (in general case may be different ).
so , you will  be able to connect from host to both guest machine (even they are different network) because your host system have virtual router/switch that provide connectivity to outside. 
if you want to communicate from one VM1 to VM2 then communication will be like:

```
VM1 --> Host machine --> VM2
```

you can communicate to host but you will not able to communicate VM1 to VM2 if you are in different network.

**Solution** : Add extra NIC to hypervisor( virtualBox/libvirt/KVM etc.) of other network . 
go to `settings` and click on `Add` then add network .
my overall meaning is that add one NIC to VM1(manual created) of vagrant-default Network that created by VM2 and add one NIC to VM2(created via vagrant) of default network that create by VM1. then you will be able to communicate.

or

if you do not want to do this next time then use vagrant file like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "IP_of_same_network",
    auto_config: false
end
```

Comment: Ok I got that :) will try and let u know !